# Coinmarketcap data nested dictionary

Tags: python, json, dictionary

Hi I am still in the beginner stages of learning python. I am trying to extract data from Coinmarketcap.com using their api system. I am able to get an output with one large dictionary but can't seem to figure out how to pull specific data. I would like to receive just the'price': and 'last updated'.

I have tried referencing .loads and slicing the data into list. I have also tried to index in the dictionaries, but the nested dictionaries in the output is making it difficult for me to understand. I have watched many youtube tutorials and googled for help, but am unable to find a solution. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
import requests

import json


url ='https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/quotes/latest'

api_key = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

headers = {'Accepts': 'application/json', 'X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY': api_key}

parameters = {'symbol': 'ADA'}

response = requests.get(url, headers = headers, params = parameters)

data = response.json()

data_str = json.dumps(data, indent = 2)

print(data_str)
```

Here is the output of the dictionary:

> {"status": {"timestamp": "2019-07-17T20:54:40.829Z", "error_code": 0, "error_message": null, "elapsed": 7, "credit_count": 1}, "data": {"ADA": {"id": 2010, "name": "Cardano", "symbol": "ADA", "slug": "cardano", "num_market_pairs": 90, "date_added": "2017-10-01T00:00:00.000Z", "tags": ["mineable"], "max_supply": 45000000000, "circulating_supply": 25927070538, "total_supply": 31112483745, "platform": null, "cmc_rank": 12, "last_updated": "2019-07-17T20:54:04.000Z", "quote": {"USD": {"price": 0.056165857414, "volume_24h": 102375843.427606, "percent_change_1h": -0.816068, "percent_change_24h": 5.42849, "percent_change_7d": -21.8139, "market_cap": 1456216147.0000284, "last_updated": "2019-07-17T20:54:04.000Z"}}}}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, you can access the value of the dictionary by simply doing

```
value = dict[key]
```

In your case, you have a nested JSON. You can access the values by chaining the keys.

Your JSON looks like

```
{
"status": {
    "timestamp": "2019-07-17T20:54:40.829Z",
    "error_code": 0,
    "error_message": null,
    "elapsed": 7,
    "credit_count": 1
},
"data": {
    "ADA": {
        "id": 2010,
        "name": "Cardano",
        "symbol": "ADA",
        "slug": "cardano",
        "num_market_pairs": 90,
        "date_added": "2017-10-01T00:00:00.000Z",
        "tags": ["mineable"],
        "max_supply": 45000000000,
        "circulating_supply": 25927070538,
        "total_supply": 31112483745,
        "platform": null,
        "cmc_rank": 12,
        "last_updated": "2019-07-17T20:54:04.000Z",
        "quote": {
            "USD": {
                "price": 0.056165857414,
                "volume_24h": 102375843.427606,
                "percent_change_1h": -0.816068,
                "percent_change_24h": 5.42849,
                "percent_change_7d": -21.8139,
                "market_cap": 1456216147.0000284,
                "last_updated": "2019-07-17T20:54:04.000Z"
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

You can access the price as

```
price = data['data']['ADA']['quote']['USD']['price']
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Despite similarity it isn't a dictionary as the built-in of Python. Is a JSON. You can parse by the 'key' values. Example:

```
import json

a = '{"status": {"timestamp": "2019-07-17T20:54:40.829Z", "error_code": 0, "error_message": null, "elapsed": 7}}'
b = json.loads(a)
print(b["status"]["elapsed"])
```

See that once you're already using requests you don't have to import json module.
Ex:

```
requests.get(url).json()[0]["your_target"])
```

Analyse the response you get, maybe the index '0' does not apply.